# MongoDB C# Linq driver with nullable types

Tags: linq, nullable, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongodb c# driver and tried the following query

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IsArchived.GetValueOrDefault())
```

where IsArchived is of type `bool?` (nullable).

I get the following runtime error:

```
Unsupported where clause: x.IsArchived.GetValueOrDefault().
```

Does anybody know how I can query nullable types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out a workaround, though it is not very nice:

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IsArchived ?? false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know we use nullable types in our domain, but can't seem to find any specific instances of quering them.  You might try this:

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IsArchived == true)
```

or this if that doesn't compile:

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IsArchived == (bool?) true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.IsArchived!= null && x.IsArchived)
```

your expression is translate to mongo query , that is not supprt the C# `GetValueOrDefault` which give you the exception

Comment: compiler complains "&& x.IsArchived" because this is not valid. using "&& x.IsArchived.Value" causes same runtime error.